# Se puede desplazar las celdas de un datagridview automáticamente

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, datagrid, tablas

Mi pregunta es que si al momento de tener el datagridview dentro del formulario sin botones ni otro objeto se le puede dar la instrucción de que se desplacen hacia abajo para visualizar todo el contenido de la tabla?

Comment: no se entiendo, como todo el contenido de la tabla? la idea es que en un grid muestres los datos relevantes para cada registro, despues si se necesitan ver un detalle seleccionas la row y abres el detalle en un form para ver ahi si todos de forma completa, pero en el grid deberias limitarse todo a lo necesario

Comment: me pregunto, quien es el que vota automaticamente todo en negativo, al menos cuando lo haga que se tome la molestia de explicarse que se debe mejorar para que se aprenda a realizar mejores preguntas, votando negativo no aporta nada a quienes recien se suman al foro

Comment: Tal vez técnicamente no me explique bien, pero a lo que quiero llegar es que en mi formulario con una base de datos que tengo conectada este mostrándose todo el contenido automáticamente como la lista de vuelos de un aeropuerto como tengo 200 filas no las puedo ver todas en la pantalla y quiero que se este desplazando hacia abajo para visualizarlas sin que yo intervenga para desplazarlo.

Comment: pero el que desplaza es el cliente usando el scroll de grid, en un desarrolo web lo haces con el scroll del browser, pero no es algo automatico el cliente se deplaza para ir viendo la lista

Comment: Ok si pues por es motivo preguntaba que si existía alguna función que yo no conozco y se pudiera realizar el scroll automático, pero creo que optaré por desarrollar en web el proyecto y buscar alguna extensión de Chrome que esa creo que si existe. Grasias de todos modos por tu respuesta rápida. Buen día!!

Answer (score 0):

Si la idea es poder desplazarte usando codigo a la ultima row se utiliza la propiedad

[FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex?view=netframework-4.8)

despues de asignar el `DataSource` asignas en la propiedad cual seria la row que quieres visualizar y se desplazara hasta esta

Puedes ver de usar la propiedad

[RowCount Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount?view=netframework-4.8)

o sino simplementes `Rows.Count` para hacer que se desplace hasta el final